# _Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher

Tags: build.gradle, arcore, kotlin-gradle-plugin

here my version is already high but then also it is showing exception. it is showing " ':ar_flutter_plugin' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50 "

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

look my kotlin version it is 1.7.10 already but then also the also it is showing exception . of ( Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher)